# Adding scroll effect on list of divs

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to add a scroll effect on list of div. I want to have active div a bit larger in size as compared to other two divs above and below it. I want to grow the active div slowly as I scroll but I'm unable to to this. Here's my code.

```js
var listItem = $(".item");
$(window).scroll(function() {
  let currentScroll = window.pageYOffset - 5;
  $(".item").removeClass("item__active");
  for (let i = 1; i < listItem.length; i++) {
    for (k = currentScroll; k < listItem[i].offsetTop - 150; k++) {
      var addfact = listItem[i].offsetTop - 150 - currentScroll;
      if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 90) {
        i = listItem.length - 1;
      }

      listItem[i - 1].classList.add("item__active");
      listItem[i].style = 'transition-duration: 1.5s';
      listItem[i].style.transform = 'scale(1.0)';
      break;

    }
  }
});
```

```css
.item {
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;

}
.item__active {
      height: 300px;
      border: 1px solid;
      width: auto;
      padding: 10px;
      margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    }
```

```html
<script
src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="item">
  <h1> Content 1 </h1>
</div>
<div class="item__active">
  <h1> Content 2 </h1>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <h1> Content 3 </h1>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <h1> Content 4 </h1>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <h1> Content 5 </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: It says you have a syntax error.

Comment: @King11  Removed error.

Comment: @ShubhamKumarGupta did you found a solution for this one?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with pure CSS very easily. NO JS REQUIRED. Here's the code:

HTML

```
<div class="item">
  <h1> Content 1 </h1>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <h1> Content 2 </h1>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <h1> Content 3 </h1>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <h1> Content 4 </h1>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <h1> Content 5 </h1>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.item {
  height: 100px;
  width: auto;
  transition: height 2s;
}

.item:hover {
  height: 200px;
}
```

This makes it so the height will change to the indicated height when the element is hovered. We can also specify a transition in css, indicating that if the specified style property changes on the target element. It should animate its transition over the declared amount of time, 2 seconds in this case.

Comment: I'm making this for a touch device and it'll not work there.

Comment: The transition hint is good but he asked for growing divs while scrolling not on hover.